# Class 'pendalf89\filemanager\widgets\TinyMce' not found

Tags: php, tinymce, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-widget

I configured all as written [README file](https://github.com/PendalF89/yii2-filemanager/blob/master/README.md) and it works on localhost.
But when I upload the site to my production server it gives me the following error:

> Class 'pendalf89\filemanager\widgets\TinyMce' not found

Here is my code:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'description')->widget(pendalf89\filemanager\widgets\TinyMce::className(), ['clientOptions' => ['...']]); ?>
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Copy `project-directory/composer.json` file to server and run `composer update` command on server.

Comment: Have some alternative ways to do this ?, my hosting provider doesn't allow to run commands. And thanks for your help.

Comment: Otherwise you have to copy all `/vendor` folder.

Comment: Yeah, I copied all folders, (/vendor also) but still not working. But all other plugins working well.

Comment: Try check on server in `project-folder/vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` file. Your plugin should be listed here, is it?

Comment: Yeah.
`pendalf89\\tinymce\\' => array($vendorDir . '/pendalf89/yii2-tinymce'),
    'pendalf89\\filemanager\\' => array($vendorDir . '/pendalf89/yii2-filemanager'),`

Comment: Are you sure it's on server, not on local files?

Comment: Yeah, I am sure, just checked out !))

Comment: Please check in `project-folder/vendor/yiisoft/extensions.php` aswell.

Comment: `'pendalf89/yii2-filemanager' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'pendalf89/yii2-filemanager',
    'version' => '9999999-dev',
    'alias' => 
    array (
      '@pendalf89/filemanager' => $vendorDir . '/pendalf89/yii2-filemanager',
    ),
  )`

Comment: Damn, i have to surrender without code access, sorry.

Comment: Ok, I try upload /vendor again and again!